# Spam popup using Google news

Tags: android, antivirus, spam, google-apps

The other day I was using Google News, clicked a Politico link, and got a popup saying Google had selected me to get a free iPad if I answered some survey questions. I didn't fall for it but I had never gotten anything like this before on my device.

I posted on the [support forum](https://support.google.com/googlenews/thread/152981565?hl=en) and some "Platinum Product Expert" said I was infected. I ran BitDefender and it found nothing, so I posted that info and the Expert said that's not serious antivirus and I should get a serious tool. I asked what tool and he said he couldn't recommend non-Google products on there and I should ask somewhere else, so here I am.

All the reviews I read say BitDefender's the best Android antivirus. Is that wrong? This hasn't happened since, and I use Google News all the time, so it seems unlikely it was caused by malware. Maybe Politico got infected? Or is there really some better tool that might detect an infection that BitDefender wouldn't?

Comment: What did you do on this popup page? Did you download anything?

Comment: No, I just looked it over and backed up to the article.

Comment: Chances are you are fine, if the antivirus found nothing and you didn't install anything the chances of an infection are nill.

Comment: Is it possible that it was legitamite advertising, presumably only promising one ipad among all survey respondents instead of one for you in particular?

Comment: No, they were spoofing Google. It looked legit till I thought about it a little.